# Evaluate C# expression inside another expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I want to use an expression in another one:

```
Expression<Func<double, double>> f = x => x * x * 27 + blah ... expression with x;

Expression<Func<double, double>> g = y => 3 + 8 * f.Compile()(y) * y * blah... expression with y and f(y);
```

This will not work when sent to LINQ to SQL because f.Compile() is unknown to SQL.

How do you evaluate the expression `f` on the variable `y` without compiling it, but still using normal syntax to define `g`?

I don't want to have to define all of `g` with some unreadable `Expression.Add`/`Expression.Multiply` etc. statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Calling functions in LINQ queries](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx) and [LINQ Extensions](http://linqextensions.codeplex.com/) project. CLinq part is irrelevant to your question, but it also includes LinqExt library, which is just what are you looking for. The same approach is also used by [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) which also provides other useful extensions for Linq.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I downloaded LinqKit from the link you gave and it works perfectly with `Invoke` and `AsExpandable`. I agree, very interesting articles.

Comment: Would have been good to show what syntax it works.

Comment: @Vladimir the thing is there was no such syntax in C# and you had to use 3rd party libraries with their own syntax or you could have implemented something on your own. Anyway it's a bit late to do anything regarding your comment, cause I haven't been using .NET for several years now.