# Expression tree condition conversion with selector

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have an entity class like

```
public class BookPage {
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

then I have an expression:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> pageIndexCondition = idx => idx == 1;
```

and the expression I want:

```
Expression<Func<BookPage, bool>> pageCondition = bookPage => bookPage.PageIndex == 1;
```

The question: How do I use `pageIndexCondition` to do LINQ-to-SQL query, or how can I convert `pageIndexCondition` into `pageCondition`?

Edit: Another solution that would be less elegant, but still meet my requirement is:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetPageIndexCondition(Expression<Func<T, int>> selector) {
     return (T item) => selector(item) < 10; // This won't work because selector is Expression, so how to implement this correctly?
}

...

var pageCondition = GetPageIndexCondition(page => page.PageIndex);
```

Comment: *Why* do you have `pageIndexCondition` to start with? Is there any reason you can't just use `pageCondition`? How flexible does `pageIndexCondition` actually need to be?

Comment: You can use `pageCondition`.

Comment: You want a generic select by id?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm implementing a class that would generate integer-set conditional expression from string, e.g. (1-8,9,10,14-15), but I ran into this problem and stuck. Yes, I could make it return the expression like `pageCondition` because it's me who control the whole codebase after all, but I think my class's concern is to generate conditional expression of an integer and I should try to separate it from my business entity types. Please see my edit for another possible approach that might make more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @tia: I wouldn't try to separate it, to be honest. Just write a method in your storage layer which accepts either a set of integers or a single one, and uses the `pageCondition` version.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978200/381333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like doing these things, though as others have said, there's probably more efficient and better ways to do it:

```
void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> pageIndexCondition = idx => idx == 1;
    Expression<Func<BookPage, bool>> converted = ExpressionConverter.Convert(pageIndexCondition);
}

public class ExpressionConverter : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static Expression<Func<BookPage, bool>> Convert(Expression<Func<int, bool>> e)
    {
        var oldParameter = e.Parameters.First();
        var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BookPage), "bp");
        Expression<Func<BookPage, int>> x = (BookPage bp) => bp.PageIndex;
        var property = ((x.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo);
        var memberAccess = Expression.Property(newParameter, property);

        var converter = new ExpressionConverter(oldParameter, memberAccess);
        return (Expression<Func<BookPage, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(converter.Visit(e.Body), newParameter);
    }

    private ParameterExpression pe;
    private Expression replacement;

    public ExpressionConverter(ParameterExpression pe, Expression replacement)
    {
        this.pe = pe;
        this.replacement = replacement;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if(node == pe)
            return replacement;

        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested it with real database query and it works very fine. However, can we replace "PageIndex" part with some kind of lambda expression?

Comment: What do you mean Lambda expression? You want the ExpressionConverter.Convert function to be more flexible?

Comment: Give me a method signature, I'll fill it out.

Comment: I mean using string to identify property name will skip compile-time checking. It would be nice if I can use something like `(BookPage page) => page.PageIndex` instead.

Comment: Edited: A bit silly as that requires two casts, which also aren't compile time checked, but edited nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pages = new List<BookPage>
                {
                    new BookPage { PageIndex = 1 }, 
                    new BookPage { PageIndex = 2 }
                };

Expression<Func<BookPage, bool>> pageCondition = bookPage => bookPage.PageIndex == 1;

BookPage result = pages.AsQueryable().Single(pageCondition);
```

If you want a generic select by id you will have to do something like;

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
{
    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }
}
```

This goes in your generic repository.